# Can I automatically run a terminal command when opening a PHPStorm project?

Tags: phpstorm, gulp

I've got a Gulp workflow that I'd like to automatically launch upon opening my project in PHPStorm. Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<s>Not possible at the moment.</s>

<s>https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11818 -- watch this and related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.</s>

---

**UPDATE:** This functionality is now implemented and available since PhpStorm v10 / WebStorm v11 -- look for it under `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Startup Tasks`.

This allows you to execute any existing (or create new) Run/Debug Configurations on project opening. This includes Gulp/Grunt tasks as they can be invoked via Run/Debug Configurations functionality.